# Relationship between cdfs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have random variable $X$ and two observers. For observer one cdf of $X$ is $F(.)$ and for observer two, it is $G(.)$. For some particular value of $x$ I am looking conditions/relations for $F$ and $G$ that guarantee $F(G^{-1}(x))\neq x$. Equivalently, $F(G^{-1}(x))<x$ or $F(G^{-1}(x))>x$. If, for instance, there is a first order stochastic dominance between $F$ and $G$, one of the inequalities are satisfied. I am looking other relevant relations. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assuming both CDFs are continuous and strictly increasing, don't you need $F(x) \gt G(x)$ or $F(x) \lt G(x)$ for all $x$ ?  Wouldn't that be a stronger condition than first order stochastic dominance?

Comment: Yes, but what I am looking a weaker one, if there is. Your suggestion is stronger, but it is hard to claim that this relationship is valid for a large class of distributions.

Comment: Essentially you are asking that $F^{-1}(x) \not = G^{-1}(x)$. Here $x$ is not a possible value of $X$ but something from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: That's true. That is, $x\in[0,1]$ and I am looking whether there is any way of obtaining those inequalities.

Comment: Monotone likelihood ratio property. But it's stronger than first order stochastic dominance (in fact implies it).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get some condition weaker than first-order stochastic dominance if $F$ and $G$ are continuous. The condition $F^{-1}(x)\neq G^{-1}(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ imply that $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$ never cross so $F$ and $G$ also never cross so you have FOSD.

If we allow some finite number of points with mass so $F$ and $G$ are have a finite number of discontinuous points (not necessarily the same) than the condition you want is that in each region of continuity either $F$ is above or below $G$ but I'm not aware that this condition has a name. Does anyone else wants to chip in?

Comment: Well actually. I am not saying the condition holds for all $x\in[0,1]$. In different context the value of $x$ changes. I thought the set of intersection points of $F$ and $G$ would be measure zero. Than, as you suggested either $F$ and $G$ would be above between two consecutive intersection point. The thing is whether there is a name for this condition or a concept related with this property.

Comment: @user64066: Why don't you clarify **in the question** what is being assumed about x? If $x$ is only one point then the question may have some reasonable answer. If the only requirement you have is that $\left\{x:F(x)=G(x)\right\}$ is a set of measure then any two "generic" CDFs will satisfy this property.

Comment: Given your interest thinking $x$ as mixed strategy NE probability for a particular strategy,say strategy $2$ might shed light on the meaning of $x$. As the game changes, clearly $x$ will change. Hope this makes sense, since my game theory knowledge is really limited.